# Forward using types in classes in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to forward access enums inside classes as below:

```
class city;

struct retro
{
   int num_blocks;
   city::street strt;  // <- city::street unknown type 
};

class city
{
   public:
    enum street
    {
       MAIN,
       FIRST,
       SECOND
    };
   private:
    ...
};
```

Is this not a valid way of doing it? What am I doing wrong here?
I fixed the problem this way:

```
class city_basic
{
   public:
    enum street
    {
       MAIN,
       FIRST,
       SECOND
    };
};

struct retro
{
   int num_blocks;
   city_basic::street strt;  // <- works fine
};

class city : public city_basic
{
   ...
};
```

Is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: Is there any reason not to declare `city` before `retro`?

Comment: Actually, yes. The problem I've shown here is a representation of what I have. My class is pretty big. And I have a bunch of structs and typedefs using types from that class. So, it's easier to find them if they come first.

Comment: If you use `retro` inside `city` you should probably show it. Creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us really helps us understand the problem better. Also, if you use `retro` inside `city`, can't it be made a pointer or reference? Then you could forward declare `retro` before `city`, and define `retro` later.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I don't use retro inside city.

Comment: Then there's no problem really, just declare `retro` after `city`. You simply can't let your preferred coding style take precedence over compiler and language reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard requires that `city` being a complete type at that point.

Basically any time you declare a variable, field of a type or accesses it's members the type has to be completely declared. The rationale is that the compiler will have to know the size of the object at that point (or in the case of accessing members know the layout).

You can on the other hand define a pointer  before the type is completely defined, but still you can't do pointer arithmetics or access members via the pointer (the compiler needs to know the size or layout for that too).

Answer (score 1):

If it is not possible to define `city` before `retro`, it may be better to define `enum city::street` outside of the class:

```
enum city_street { MAIN, FIRST, SECOND };

struct retro {
    int num_blocks;
    city_street strt;
};

class city {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Since C++11, it is possible to forward-declare enums.  The trouble is using a member of an incomplete class.

Comment: @aschepler: I'm using c++11. Any suggestion how to forward-declare?

Comment: `enum city_street : unsigned int;` - but this doesn't make it a member of `city`.